# Upload a file using perl

Tags: perl, upload, automation

Can you suggest some ways to do the task of uploading a file to a website.
On clicking the Upload button, the file browse window opens. On selecting the file, it is uploaded. **There is no page refresh**

This is the html code for the Upload button:

```
<div id="upload-import-link" class="qq-upload-button string-file-import" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0pt; top: 0pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
</div>
```

This is the POST request/response on clicking upload button:

**Response Headers**

```
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  97
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 12 Jun 2012 16:10:46 GMT
Server  Apache
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  51
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Cookie  __utma=15051113.842126841.1338136284.1339431202.1339515554.17; __utmz=15051113.1338136284.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmv=15051113.customer|1=l=%2Fstring%2Fauth%2Fform%2F=1; mp_super_properties=%7B%22all%22%3A%20%7B%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22http%3A//mygengo.com/string/auth/form/%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22mygengo.com%22%2C%22mp_name_tag%22%3A%20%22hitenny%20%3Chitenny@gmail.com%3E%22%2C%22translator%22%3A%20%220%22%7D%2C%22events%22%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%22funnels%22%3A%20%7B%7D%7D; MintUnique=1; _chartbeat2=z6ana05w3hf1zj7u.1338136288894.1339517190647.00000000000001; myG_last_visit=1338169443; myG_last_activity=1338826430; WRUID=0; ki_u=0e6659b9-ae82-145c-fe0f-662e130e2629; ki_t=1338169390734%3B1338821597245%3B1338826464592%3B3%3B22; MintUniqueMonth=1338476400; myG_myGSession=gSIDOJ%2Bt7MKGDkhsbGvQLBdo6N9w%2BUTX8R8Ab6FXZYFwyexnE2oc91UOPr5kmhL9rhfGfgHuUIDvO88XRnrAsgNom3BYapudUZgsG9LaeJznQUz%2Fl2O23wCQGnoKpQx%2BbFZ01UoGUdeoe2DlZeRUoQZybYLg3tElZhZpnAa%2Byc6ZUxkPoNbDWNjMN8dx9oEhZVbccOILVe71sow2UcFD%2FuCWoZ9PLqn3yy%2FxpTlM5CkcAgzPDhx4pYmP%2BMmBowB5uprGvHtnzedX0O1TJzEItXH7Fkn9Jqvef1O41xI0Sc7FmQk6%2FPvTaDjiV%2FYaj9Yl7pLM7PDBn624MEUhDrpS9fZdKn%2F8jCP0irqGueE88hLoS29WvmglpKR9pTKLikTdGjlj0gp9vraKWgtXYxAZPsHOW54TryjBkGguCQQ8xDe01zDi3AzR6XY30z5kh%2FNyT3aoLLu4l0D3zva9dDR%2F7mH67Q%2FaGBWGIOi10iWxrm2vf%2B2kP%2BTY8BKKxaDizyuS%2FqeaA%2BOSHF7JxuWUsy%2FFjMiH0OPiv706WoscyEg1Tpw%2F8MM2XOXe0aoaNJARxdkg8dqGc0hinijGGm4CrX58wBos08VuSIDZqEs0j6pH0Y%2BCTZK9Zqp4QR1tI%2FwkKH8I2QhT3edY8AwuWaL63Y8zCkPEjY0NIkg3ghcg3Y7fltDwr0Eb9G28cKU2TaFix1eOwToIUY9n%2FxtqEChz5qAniXYs71kDQCW8E9IghXKLx%2FhIpgESntp0UB9WGWnrXuSB; myG_myGEE2=onWxzY3JSmo%252B5IZJoRCWtaORPx1G%252F8FoZp2rGOMT9Qyw8gV6piPHcs%252BwZy50Z0I5c8M8646XcYI52a3Y2%252B%252B9Zm%252F8LKIJTzV31lELYqIrDmn4U%252F6McIe1DZ4MzhWeTIZMP976REP4OsSgl2MSurrRlqrr%252BGUum2GRIiym3a42M8OGfldcB9srNL6EKGGVKoPXJPII57mI2Hdnn%252FzQGR6%252FG4x11VCIO3cceVwM2tJqwkqj1xtPiw2q8YPdkJk%252BYMxfTLWABnow9BS3YtSG2rMZYMaiTEnGnzJ8vEBIUThH7WGOjNU%252FPSO8beKVYph3tJ9XqwLPTAG9LXrjuQXi1%252B4bthgvUjPxdUhROMeqkkmwLZSfW72JQUfV3Dh5lzmfRLr3yfXDb3WAPTJ265aGApx5fYTb%252B0wkoi6NGh52P0gBWtEU11%252FXEmsrQu8NXVNoU870X8Z%252FW1nXdRJmU8qUNDr8T9S2CVpNJ1VdrfLbhw7eX5BPw8J2AyZnPfGgdxbj7eWk1e%252BbO1PHAx%252FSycAB3ZSm9%252BBUYcGjKefoL0PsauuBtF%252BP42Gb3oJoxPfkWqESeLFlsZsJMy7bs9vN3fymfbOpdg%253D%253D; myG_TrackingID=223.235.210.6031066401324182719160536834612890008944fccde5b5e93f7.44148718; __utmb=15051113.40.10.1339515554; __utmc=15051113; _SUPERFLY_nosample=1
Host    mygengo.com
Referer http://mygengo.com/string/p/perl-test-1/admin/languages/import/en
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-File-Name 1.php
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

I explored some ways like `WWW::Selenium`. But it has limitation that it will work only in Firefox 3 etc. Please suggest some way to achieve this.

**EDIT**

I tried this code:

```
my $file = 'D:\oDesk\MyGengo Integration\1.php';
my $url = 'http://mygengo.com/string/p/perl-test-1/admin/languages/import/en';
my $req = POST $url, Content_Type => 'form-data', 
                          Content => [
                                      submit => 1,
                                      upfile => [ $file ]
                                     ];
my $response = $ua->request($req);
```

which gives this error:

```
Can't locate object method "POST" via package "http://mygengo.com/string/p/perl-test-1/admin/languages/import/en" 
(perhaps you forgot to load "http://mygengo.com/string/p/perl-test-1/admin/languages/import/en"?) at D:\oDesk\MyGengo Integration\myGengoIntegration line 124.
(in cleanup) Error requesting http://localhost:5555/selenium-server/driver/:
500 Can't call method "FETCH" on an undefined value
```

Comment: `WWW::Selenium` works only in Firefox 3? Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Zaid, Till yesterday I was getting error when using attach_file(), saying it will work only in Firefox 3. Now the error seems to be gone. But still the upload does not work.

Comment: Here's an example that uses LWP::UserAgent:  http://lena.franken.de/perl_hier/uploadingfiles/index.html

Comment: @David, tried your code. Please check my edit

Comment: Actually not my code :-)  Just a page I found doing a search.  'POST' comes out of the module HTTP::Request::Common.  So, it looks like you forgot to add a 'use' statement for that module, i.e. 'use HTTP::Request::Common'  Of course, you also need one for LWP::UserAgent (look at the 'use' statements in the code sample I cited earlier for an example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a perl CGI script to do this task.

The following article explain all the steps in detail:
http://www.sitepoint.com/uploading-files-cgi-perl/